# Call javascript using asp:button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to call a javascript function stored in separate js file using below code from aspx file

```
<asp:Panel ID="constraintPanel" runat="server">
  <div class="rightColumn">
    <div class="parseButtonDiv">
    <asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" class="button" Text="Parse" 
     OnClick="DoParseExpression();"/>  
    </div>
  </div> 
</asp:Panel>
```

The on click call is not going through.

Looking for suggestions

Thanks

Comment: You have to use OnClientClick https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you can show your js method, It will help to give proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [OnClientClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" class="button" Text="Parse" 
     OnClick="DoParseExpression();" OnClientClick="JavaScriptMethod();"/>
```

> Client method will invoke first then it'll go to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add simple change to your code as below.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" class="button" Text="Parse" OnClick="DoParseExpression()" OnClientClick="return JSMethod()"/>
```

You can add your js file as normal way in your html page.
After adding above change at first it call Java Script method and then trigger asp method according to js method response.

**NOTE:** If this doesn't work, show your js method, then I can give correct solution according to your purpose.

Comment: DoParseExpression = function () {
    // Set options for JQuery request.
    var expressionText = $('[id$="TextBox"]')[0].value;
    var options = {
        type: "POST",
        url: "../WebServices/ExpressionService.asmx/ParseExpression",
        data: '{ constraint: "' + expressionText + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnComplete,
        error: Failed,
        async: false
    };

    $.ajax(options);
};

Comment: I have added the JS function could you please help me out here?

Comment: DoParseExpression() is your Java Script funtion?

Comment: Isn't there any ASP method?

Comment: Yes its javascript function

Comment: No there isn't any asp method

Comment: ok. Then remove OnClick=".." and keep only OnClientClick="DoParseExpression()"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165637/discussion-between-akshay-kulkarni-and-dhananjaya).

Answer (score -1):

In your case the OnClick triggers a request to server. You need to use OnClientClick https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx